# SVG slow loading

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I'm adding SVGs to my webpage dynamically, using a custom function:

```
    function appendSVGImageButton(parent, child, x, y, w, h, colour, svg, target){

        var url = svgURL + svg + '.svg';

        //create holder
        var holderID = child+"_holder";
        var holderDiv = $("<div id='"+holderID+"' class='noselect' style='left:"+x+"px; top:"+y+"px; width:"+w+"px; height:"+h+"px; position:absolute; background-color:"+colour+"; overflow:hidden;'></div>");
        $("#"+parent).append(holderDiv);

        //create svg
        var svgID = child+"_svg";
        var svgObj = $("<object  data='"+url+"' type='image/svg+xml' style='left:0px; top:0px; width:"+w+"px; height:"+h+"px; position:absolute;'></object>");
        $("#"+holderID).append(svgObj);

        //create button
        var buttonID = child+"_button";
        var buttonDiv = $("<div id='"+buttonID+"' class='noselect' style='left:0px; top:0px; width:"+w+"px; height:"+h+"px; position:absolute; cursor: pointer;'></div>");
        $("#"+holderID).append(buttonDiv);
        var div = document.getElementById(buttonID);    
        div.addEventListener('click', target);

    }
```

Which is called like this from my main file:

```
appendSVGImageButton('productView', 'closeProductView', 19 * bD, 0, bD, bD, 'white', 'closeBig', closeProductView);
```

But as I layout the various content on the page, the SVGs load a good second after the rest of the content. Here is an example SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 28.3 28.3" style="enable-background:new 0 0 28.3 28.3;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
        @import url("http://www.example.com/temp/wp-content/themes/new/style.css");
    </style>
<g id="blue">
    <line class="st6" x1="6.8" y1="21.5" x2="21.5" y2="6.8"/>
</g>
<g id="red">
    <g>
        <line class="st18" x1="21.5" y1="21.5" x2="6.8" y2="6.8"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="white_only_in_heart">
</g>
</svg>
```

I'm wondering if the @import is slowing business down? I did originally have the classes defined within the style tags, but it was still quite slow. Any ideas?

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: If styling was the issue, the screen estate would already be reserved at an earlier time for the object element. More likely you will have to look at when your `appendSVGImageButton` function is called. Does it wait for the document `load` event (and thus for all other resources being loaded)?

Comment: You aren't creating a dynamic SVG at all, just creating an `object` element with the URL of the SVG. It probably won't run `appendSVGImageButton` until the entire DOM is ready, since it is inserting that object into the existing `parent` element.

Comment: @ccprog the SVGs are loaded after the document load event, several times, depending on where the user navigates around the screen. It's a single page website, with lots of divs being appended and removed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you can try using a dataURL. I removed the import style from your svg and converted it to a dataURL:

```
"data:image/svg+xml;base64,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"
```

Now, in the place where you are doing:

```
"<object  data='"+url+"'...
```

replace the `url` with the data url I provided. You will need to load the style separately. Does change anything?

Comment: Data url content cannot be styled externally. They need to be self-contained and and cannot be accessed from the parent document.

Comment: Yeah I forgot it. However it is a good idea to try this option because if it still loading slow than it is something else. Btw he could have inlined the script but I don't have that version. Let's see what happens

Comment: Not with that example SVG, as it is actually invisible without style applied. (Only grafical elements are lines.)

Comment: Let me see, aww yep, he should have put some stroke and stroke-with attributes...

Comment: @ibowankenobi I've tried with self contained styles within the SVG and using the at import, with no change in load times.

Comment: Could you perhaps add an eventlistener on the  "load" event on window and readystatechange event on the document and console.log(Date.now) to see the difference in between? If you are using Chrome you can already do this at the inspector. Or is there a fiddle where I can see this behavior you see?